# Mathematical description of higher spin gauge theories

Tags: differential-geometry, field-theory, gauge-theory, curvature, higher-spin

Ordinary Yang-Mills gauge theory giving spin 1 gauge bosons can be mathematically described by connection 1-forms and curvature of principal bundles. I wonder, what the proper mathematical description of [higher spin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-spin_theory) [gauge theory](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/higher+spin+gauge+theory) is, so whether there is also some differential geometric description.